# How to Use Custom Dictionary Class for DynamicComponent Mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I Like to use a custom IDictionary class for my DynamicComponent mappings:

```
class ObservableDictionary : Hashtable, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

when mapping lists it's possible to use a custom collection type as follows:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Items).CollectionType<ObservableCollection<ItemClass>>();
```

But how can i do this with DynamicComponents? There is no CollectionType Method.

```
mapping.DynamicComponent(
    x => x.DynamicFields,
    c => {
            c.Map(x => x["fld_num"]).CustomType(typeof(int));
            c.Map(x => x["shortdesc"]).CustomType(typeof(string));
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your custom Dictionary has an inner dictionary holding the data then you can

```
mapping.Component(x => x.DynamicFields, c => c.DynamicComponent(
    Reveal.Member<CustomDictionary, IDictionary>("_innerDictionary"),
    c => {
        c.Map(x => x["fld_num"]).CustomType(typeof(int));
        c.Map(x => x["shortdesc"]).CustomType(typeof(string));
    })
);
```